# How can I call field level validation methods defined on both child and parent serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a scenario where I have 3 serializers that each have a set of the same fields, as well as their associated `serializer.validate_field` methods:

```
class Serializer1(serializers.Serializer):
    same_field_1 = serializers.BooleanField()
    same_field_2 = serializers.BooleanField()
    ...
    validate_field_1()
    validate_field_2()
    ...

class Serializer2(serializers.Serializer):
    same_field_1 = serializers.BooleanField()
    same_field_2 = serializers.BooleanField()
    ...
    validate_field_1()
    validate_field_2()
    ...

class Serializer3(serializers.Serializer):
    same_field_1 = serializers.BooleanField()
    same_field_2 = serializers.BooleanField()
    ...
    validate_field_1()
    validate_field_2()
    ...
```

**NOTE**: each class contains other fields and validate methods that aren't shared with the other serializers as well.

I would like to bring the common fields and validate methods up into a parent class, then have each of these child classes inherit from that parent class.

The issue then becomes, how do I run the validation defined on the child **and** the parent? I don't see any specific documentation discussing how we can run the `is_valid()` cycle on the parent class as well as the child class.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, can you give an example serializer with inheritance where validation is not working? Are you talking about overriding one of the `validate_*` methods in a child class and wanting the overridden method in the parent class to be called?

Answer (score 0):

make a call to ParentSerializer().validate_my_field in child's validate_my_field

```
class BaseSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    my_field = serializers.CharField()
    def validate_my_field(self, value):
        # raise ValidationError if needed
        return value

class ChildSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    def validate_my_field(self, value):
        value = super().validate_my_field(value)
        # raise Exception by child
        return value
```